# To cross table row when checkbox change state to 'checked' (pure Javascript)

Tags: javascript, checkbox, dom-events, addeventlistener

There is a simple markup.
I need to cross text in the same table row as checkbox when checkbox change state to 'checked'.
Any help appreciated.

```js
 function watcher(){
                var checkboxElements = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox");
                
                for(var i = 0; i<checkboxElements.length; i++){
                    checkboxElements[i].addEventListener('change', function(){
                        if(checkboxElements[i].checked === true) {
                            table.querySelector("table").rows[i].style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

```html
<table class='table'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class='checkbox' type='checkbox'>
            </td>
            <td>
                test
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class='checkbox' type='checkbox'>
            </td>
            <td>
                test
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

My code seems doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the ancestor using the function `closest()` along with the context `this` to get the reference of the `checkbox` element.

```js
function watcher() {
  var checkboxElements = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox");

  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxElements.length; i++) {
    checkboxElements[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
      if (this.checked) {
        this.closest('tr').style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
      }
    });
  }
}

watcher();
```

```html
<table class='table'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class='checkbox' type='checkbox'>
    </td>
    <td>
      test
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class='checkbox' type='checkbox'>
    </td>
    <td>
      test
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```